# What methods are available in the WinAPI for accessing programs in the system tray?

Tags: c#, winapi

What DLLs would have functions for accessing things in the System Tray? Do I even need the winapi, or are there classes already available in the Class Library for this? I'm hoping to find a way to emulate all the functionality of the system tray, i.e. the icons, the mouseover text, and the capability to display the context menu.

Comment: Are you writing an entire replacement shell (i.e. replacing explorer.exe), or do you just want to hook the notification area and replace it with your own? What you have to do depends largely on which one of these you want. By the way, the correct name is "notification area" not "system tray".

Comment: do you want to add you one in system tray or you want to real all open application in system tray ?

Comment: codeka is on to me... I want a big project, something to really stretch my abilities. I want to replace explorer.exe just as a development exercise. I would also like all existing apps to be compatible and I know plenty of them only exist, or primarily exist, in the 'notification area' (thanks again codeka).

I've already had my share of fun using the NotifyIcon to place my own apps in the notification area, that's not the direction I want to take here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate tray icons, retrieve tooltips, emulate single click, double and right click. See this article which explains how to do it with winapi: [Shell Tray Info - Arrange your system tray icons](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/ShellTrayInfo.aspx)

Comment: Do you know if these WinAPI calls also work in Windows 7 or Vista? Upon running the app on the site, a messagebox is displayed telling me it'll only run on XP.

Comment: @Corey Ogburn - you are getting the message because the author of the app has tested it only on XP. If you want to you can download the source code and remove the check to see how it performs on Vista/7 Taskbar has changed quite a lot so it is quite possible that the app will not work. You can use spy++ to see if you can make necessary changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx) function to work with tray icons natively. With .NET there is [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class you can use, which does the job.

Comment: The question is about enumerating existing icons, not just adding them for current process.

Comment: Somehow I don't see a word "enumerate" in the original question.